# Not getting desired output in Creating a Multiclient Chat Server?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create a multiclient chat sort of server in which we have multiple clients connecting to server and whatever message a client enters, it gets displayed to all the clients(including the client who sent the message). I am not getting this output, instead the message just echoes only on the sender client and no other client. Code is quite long, hence i am displaying snippets of whichever code i think will help you understand error. In case, it is not enough, just comment which part you require. Thanks in advance. I am stuck on this since about hour and half, so i appreciate whatever help i would get.

**The Server Class**

```
public class Multiserver {

ServerSocket serversocket;
Socket socket;
ArrayList<Socket> al = new ArrayList<Socket>();
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;

Multiserver() throws IOException
{

     serversocket = new ServerSocket(1036);
     System.out.println("Server started on port 1036");

    while(true)
    {

        socket = serversocket.accept();
        System.out.println(socket);
        al.add(socket);
        Mythread  thread = new Mythread(socket, al);
        thread.start();
    } 
}
```

**Thread used in server class**

```
public class Mythread extends Thread{

Socket socket;
ArrayList al;
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;

Mythread(Socket socket, ArrayList al) 
{
     this.socket = socket;
     this.al = al;}

     public void run()
     {
         try{

             String data ="";
             dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             data = dis.readUTF();
             if(!data.equals("stop"))
             {
                 broadcast(data);
             }
             else
             {
                 dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                 // data = dos.readUTF();
                 dos.writeUTF(data);
                 dos.flush();
                 //dos.close();
             }

         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Run "+e);
         }


   }
   public void broadcast(String data)
   {
       try{
           Iterator it = al.iterator();
           while(it.hasNext())
           {
              Socket socket1 = (Socket)it.next();
               dos = new DataOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream());
               dos.writeUTF(data);
               dos.flush();


           }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Broadcast running "+ e);
       }
   }
}
```

**The client class**

```
public class Multiclient {

Socket socket;
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;
Multiclient() throws IOException
{
    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1036);
    System.out.println(socket);
    Mythreadc my = new Mythreadc(socket);
    my.start();
}
```

**Thread used in client class**

```
public class Mythreadc extends Thread{

DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;
Socket socket;
Mythreadc(Socket socket)throws IOException
{
    this.socket = socket;}

public void run()
{
    BufferedReader br = null; 
    try{
       br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      String data = "";
      do{

          data = br.readLine();
          dos.writeUTF(data);
          System.out.println(data);
          dos.flush();
      }
      while(!data.equals("stop"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Client input "+e);
    }
    finally{
        try{
            br.close();
            dis.close();
            dos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Closing "+e);
        }
    }
}    
}
```

I am sorry i have put on such a long code, almost all the program. But i feel it is necessary to understand where the problem lies.I have tried and i think it lies in the part where we display data written in the client's socket in the client thread class but i don't know what it is ???

**#EDIT: Forgot to mention. The client stops when he sends the message "Stop"!**

Comment: Why are you still using non-generic iterators for your ArrayList of Sockets? You can simplify your code, and gain type-safety, by writing `for(Socket socket1 : al)`. (Incidentally, you forgot to give ArrayList a generic type in MyThread, although it has one in Multiserver).

Comment: yeah, i get that. I was writing the rough form.. i just wanted to run it once and then simplify and shorten all the code. But it got stuck on the first intance itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code that are preventing the clients from displaying more than one message.

**Problem one:** Your client code never actually displays or prints out the messages it receives from the server. The line

```
dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

creates an OutputStream you can use to write data to the socket, i.e. send messages to the server. But you never use the socket's InputStream, which is what you need to do to read data from the socket, i.e. receive messages from the server. When you see a message printed out on the client, you're actually just seeing the result of

```
System.out.println(data);
```

which has your client print the message it just sent.

In order for the client to accept input from the user and read messages from the server at the same time, you should probably use two threads on the client. One thread can just be the client thread you already wrote, since it takes care of accepting input from the user. The other thread should look something like this:

```
public class ClientReaderThread extends Thread {

Socket socket;

ClientReaderThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try (BufferedReader serverReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))){

        String fromServer = serverReader.readLine();;
        while(fromServer != null) {
             if (fromServer.equals("stop")) 
                break;
            System.out.println(fromServer);
            fromServer = serverReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Client error! Got exception: " + e);
    }
}

}
```

(Note that I use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to construct the reader, which takes care of closing it when the client stops).

Then in your main client class, start both threads with the same socket:

```
Multiclient() throws IOException
{
    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1036);
    System.out.println(socket);
    Mythreadc my = new Mythreadc(socket);
    ClientReaderThread reader = new ClientReaderThread(socket);
    my.start();
    reader.start();
}
```

**Problem two:** Your server only reads and echoes a single line from each client, because the socket thread that handles each client (`Mythread`) doesn't contain a loop. With your setup of creating a single thread per client, `run()` only gets called once per client, so that `run()` method needs to handle every message that client sends.

Here's how the `run()` method in the server's thread should look:

```
public void run() {
    try (BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))){

        String data = inStream.readLine();
        while(data != null) {
            if(data.equals("stop"))
                break;
            broadcast(data);
            data = inStream.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Run exception "+e);
    } finally {
        al.remove(socket); //This is important to do
    }

}
```

I made an additional important change here: at the end of the `run()` method, when either the client disconnected or an exception happened, the thread **removes its socket from the ArrayList.** This ensures that other server threads, which all reference the same ArrayList, don't try to broadcast to the socket of a client that has disconnected. If you neglect to do this, you'll get an exception when a client sends a message to the server after another client has disconnected.

**Miscellaneous notes**

- As I mentioned in my comment, you should give `al` a type of `ArrayList<Socket>` inside the thread class, and use a for-each loop instead of an Iterator to iterate over it in `broadcast()`.
- I'm using `BufferedReader` instead of `DataInputStream` to read from the socket. That's because `DataInputStream.readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` are deprecated, and have been replaced with `BufferedReader.readLine()` and `PrintWriter.println()`.
- The streams like `dis` and `dos` don't need to be instance variables in your thread classes, since they are only ever used inside the `run()` method. They can be local variables inside `run()`, like I did with `inStream` in my new `run()` method.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan It's really hard to read code inside a comment like that, so I'm not sure, but I think you're still making a mistake because you don't put the `serverReader.readLine()` line inside the while loop. You need to read from the server repeatedly, not just once.

Comment: No, i did put that line inside the while loop, But still it didnt work. I don't know where the problem is and its pretty messed up and confusing as well

Comment: @KirtyBhushan My initial answer overlooked a problem: displaying messages form the server in the same thread as you accept input from the client will cause the server messages to not print until the client enters some input. It's better to do them in separate threads, as I say in my new answer.

Comment: I did that now. Two threads, with BufferedReader, it displayed no output still, but with DataInputStream, it echoes the first message of sender client to all clients and then the echo function doesn't work for rest typed messages. Just the first message in senders client, be it any client!

Comment: @KirtyBhushan Ah, that's because you forgot to put a loop in your server thread, so it stops after processing one message. I updated my answer to show how to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks alot sir, for your time and patience! I did it and now it runs perfectly, thanks for clearing me out! And i will keep in mind the tips you provided !

Answer (score -1):

I think you just missed passing the **ArrayList of Sockets Users Currently Connected to The Server** to the thread

and Instead of Posting your Server Class You have just posted Client Program 2 times anyway ,

Your **ServerClass** should be build in this way  : -

As soon as **ServerClass** recieves the request from any client, **Server Class** should add the Socket into ArrayList and create New Thread and just pass both to the MyThread Class

**Edit :** 
It seems you haven't written code for Displaying the data you will get from the server .

At Client Side for Sending the Message You can simple write that in Main Thread that is under Your **Client Class's** Main Mehtod

You  actually needed **Thread** at client side not for sending the message but rather for Listening the Message from the server,
because you never known when **anyone** can send you the message but you will always know when **you** want to send message to anybody connected to this chat App

Now coming to the Coding Part :

**Client Class**

```
public class Multiclient {

Socket socket;
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;
Multiclient() throws IOException
{
    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1036);
    System.out.println(socket);
    Mythreadc my = new Mythreadc(socket);
    my.start();
    /**
     * Here write out the code for taking input from Standard Console
     */
    BufferedReader br = null; 

   try{
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  String data = "";
  do{

      data = br.readLine();
      dos.writeUTF(data);
      System.out.println(data);
      dos.flush();
  }
  while(!data.equals("stop"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Client input "+e);
}
}
```

**Client Thread**

```
        try{

         String data ="";
         dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while(data.equalsIgnorCase("stop")){
         data = dis.readUTF();
         System.out.println("Server Message : "+data);
    }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Run "+e);
     }
```

Client Thread is not complete but i think this information is sufficient enough .

Hope It help you out , Your problem do remind me of College Days :)

Comment: Sorry, i mistakenly put in the wrong code in the server class. Now edited! check it out !

Comment: Check out the Edited Answer , Hope it helps